# setInterval count down is not works when the browser tab is not active or focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As part of my react app, setInterval specific count-down is not works exactly with same seconds when the browser tab is either inactive or not focused scenario.

What the alternative or best solution to overcome this issue?

```
const [inactiveTimer, setInactiveTimer] = useState(120);
 useEffect(() => {    
     const inactiveInterval = setInterval(() => {
         if (timeoutInterval > 0) {
             setInactiveTimer(timeoutInterval - 1);
         } else if (timeoutInterval === 0) {
             setShowModal(true);
         }
     }, 1000);
     return () => {
        clearInterval(inactiveInterval);
     };
 }, []);
```

Comment: Check out this page.
https://usefulangle.com/post/280/settimeout-setinterval-on-inactive-tab

Comment: @DharmikPatel: In my case its not actually taking one second while the tab is inactive instead it took more than 1 seconds even i mentioned 1000 as delay... and when we open multiple tab each tab taking different latency in the invocation of seitnterval... so i cant use based on visibilitychange to call my function..in any case i have to call the same funtion.